# Syntax Error in using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm not sure what is wrong in the syntax of my code, something wrong with returning the address location of the pointers of firstname and secondname.

```
string names()
{
    string firstname;
    string secondname;

    int *p_firstname = & firstname;
    int *p_secondname = & secondname;

    cout << "Enter your first name: ";
    cin >> firstname;
    cout << "Enter your second name: ";
    cin >> secondname;

    return &p_firstname, &p_secondname;
}
```

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: what is `return &p_firstname, &p_secondname;` supposed to do ?

Comment: The Error message is `Error 4 error C2664: 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string(std::initializer_list<_Elem>,const std::allocator<char> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int **' to 'const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &' c:\programming\c++\visual studio\temp\temp\main.cpp 306 1 Temp
`

Comment: I am trying to return both values(firstname&secondname) via a pointer to another function.

Comment: `int *p_firstname = & firstname;` should not compile or at least give a warning.  You try to assign a pointer to a string to a pointer to an int.  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What meaning do you expect of an integer pointer to a string?

Comment: You are seriously confused ;-)

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to do? Return addresses in order to see where the variables are (or rather were) in memory?

Comment: I've said so, "I am trying to return both values(firstname&secondname) via a pointer to another function" What do you not understand?

Comment: `error: cannot convert ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ to ‘int*’ in initialization`

Answer (score 2):

Try return your two strings with a `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`:

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> names() {
    ...
    return std::make_pair(firstname, secondname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return two int pointer addresses? as a string type?

try

```
return firstname + secondname;
```